# storing a cookie on IE (11)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer, cookies

I'm trying to store a cookie in an input field which works just fine on Chrome but doesn't work on IE-11. Can anyone tell me what I'm missing so this is cookie can also work on IE? Here's my code.

Javascript:

```
function setCookie(key, value) {
    var expires = new Date();
    expires.setTime(expires.getTime() + (1 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
    document.cookie = key + '=' + value + ';expires=' + expires.toUTCString();
}

function getCookie(key) {
    var keyValue = document.cookie.match('(^|;) ?' + key + '=([^;]*)(;|$)');
    return keyValue ? keyValue[2] : null;
}

function myfunction() {
    setCookie("input1", '1');
    alert(getCookie("input1"));
    document.homeForm.input1.value = getCookie("input1");
}
```

HTML

```
<form name="myform">
<input type=text name=input1 value=""/>
</form>
```

Comment: Your form is called `myform` but your code refers to `document.homeForm...` - is that a type in your code or just this post?

Comment: @Emissary just this post

Comment: This code worked fine on IE 11 for me. Do you have cookies enabled?

Comment: I've added an answer with images, but if this does not help solve your issue, please do not accept this answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@progx here are some images of this working for me on IE 11. But just to insure cross browser compatibility you should enclose your attribute values in quotes.

```
<input type="text" name="input1" value=""/>
```

vs

```
<input type=text name=input1 value=""/>
```

Below is the code as used and images of the working code.
Code used:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() { 
    myfunction( );
});

function setCookie(key, value) {
var expires = new Date();
expires.setTime(expires.getTime() + (1 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
document.cookie = key + '=' + value + ';expires=' + expires.toUTCString();
}

function getCookie(key) {
var keyValue = document.cookie.match('(^|;) ?' + key + '=([^;]*)(;|$)');
return keyValue ? keyValue[2] : null;
}

function myfunction() {
setCookie("input1", '1');
alert(getCookie("input1"));
document.myform.input1.value = getCookie("input1");
}
</script>
<style>

</style>
<body>
<form name="myform">
<input type=text name=input1 value=""/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

[image: alert image]

[image: input image]

[image: editor image]

[image: console image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help and time!!